# insertrowsafter Function Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to this so probably an easy answer.

I need a script that will insert a number of rows after row 7, but the number of rows will depend on the value in a specific cell.  How do i reference this cell in the script?

```
function CreateRacecard() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 // This inserts rows after the seventh row
 sheet.insertRowsAfter(7,?????);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want the cell is in another sheet declare it with that way

```
var numRows=ss.getSheetByName('SheetName').getRange('Cell').getValue();
```

fixed script :

```
function CreateRacecard() {

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

     //Number of rows according to the cell
     var numRows=sheet.getRange('C1').getValue();

     // This inserts rows after the seventh row
     sheet.insertRowsAfter(7, numRows);

    }
```